# Do structs inside Box::new need curly braces

Tags: rust

Do empty structures inside `Box::new()` need curly braces? If not, is there a preferred style?

```rust
struct Empty;

// are these equivalent?

fn get_empty_box() -> Box<Empty> {
  Box::new(Empty)
}

fn get_empty_box_alt() -> Box<Empty> {
  Box::new(Empty {})
}
```

Comment: Note that the `Box` here is a bit misleading - the exact same syntax would be applicable to creating a bare `Empty`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on how they are defined.

If they are defined as `struct Foo {}` then yes.

If they are defined as `struct Foo();` then they need parentheses or braces, but it's uncommon to see them with braces.

If they're defined as `struct Foo;` then they don't need braces (although they can accept them) and usually instantiated without braces.

The technical reason for that is that `struct Foo;` defines, in addition to the struct itself, a constant with the same name that contains an instance of the struct. That is, `const Foo: Foo = Foo {};`. When you spell `Foo` without braces you just copy this constant.

In a similar fashion, tuple structs (`struct Foo();`) define, in addition to the struct itself, a function that instantiates it: `fn Foo() -> Foo { Foo {} }`.

Comment: I had no idea you could use braces with the other declaration syntaxes. That's interesting.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo yup: `struct Foo(i32); const F: Foo = Foo { 0: 42 };` :)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Not just that, it even has a semantic difference with tuple structs. `let foo = Foo(&temporary)` drops temporaries at the end of the sentence (which can cause problems), but `let foo = Foo { 0: &temporary }` extends them to the end of the scope.